# Windows 7, moving software / Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

What started quite small grew bigger each hour.

I want to migrate an existing Windows 7, both for backup and maintenance and then run it as a Virtual machine.

The computer is cloned to a VHD, but runs very slowly.
Since the machine is 64 bit, it's not that strange.

I just need the software installed, changing guest OS is not an issue.

How would you do this?

Software on 64bit VHD --> Windows 32 bit environment.

Comment: I already know this, but the solution is still the easiest way to bullet proof a working computer with software that is hard to replace. Do you have any useful answers?